# Binding data to MapElements in a MapControl in XAML (UWP)

Tags: xaml, binding, uwp, windows-10-universal

I've hit a bump in the dev of my app.
I'm trying to bind data to a MapControl and MapElements.

My data is contained in an ObservableCollection.

My issues :

- Binding a geoposition to the Center property of the MapControl does nothing at all when the mode is OneTime or OneWay. When I select TwoWays, it works. But I don't want it TwoWays :)
- Adding a MapElement doesn't work when done via XAML. Either I've the type string displayed on the MapControl, either I've Nothing at all. I followed different advices from StackOverflow (ie [Binding a MapIcon in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35132164/binding-a-mapicon-in-xaml)), but none seems to work in my case.

I'm using the latest VS2017 version, and targeting 15063 to 16299.
I've already hit some bumps using the MapControl on a UWP app (differences between PC and Mobile as it seems the Mobile Component is based on Here where the PC Component seems based on Bing).

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: For a precision, the items I try to add to the MapElements via XAML are MapIcon and MapPolygon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah this is a active bug in the Binding for the control. I had this issue too, it never worked when I tried to bind the `Center` of the map control to a property in my `viewmodel`, but since I found out that it's an active issue, I created a `TwoWay` binding with my property with the `set` method of the property doing nothing like below:

```
private BasicGeoposition mapCenter;
public BasicGeoposition MapCenter
{ 
    get{return mapCenter;}
    set{}
}
```